# Creating a Schedule Task using VBScript to run as Admin without asking for Admin rights?

Tags: windows, vbscript, scheduled-tasks, admin, uac

I am using the code at the bottom to create a Scheduled Task which runs within 30 seconds after setting it up. It runs Notepad as an example. The original program requires Admin rights to run. So it needs to set the **Run with highest privileges** setting. How to set it using VBScript? The important part is that the VBScript must not require admin rights to run this code for setting this option.

```
' This sample schedules a task to start notepad.exe 30 seconds
' from the time the task is registered.
'------------------------------------------------------------------

' A constant that specifies a time-based trigger.
const TriggerTypeTime = 1
' A constant that specifies an executable action.
const ActionTypeExec = 0   

'********************************************************
' Create the TaskService object.
Set service = CreateObject("Schedule.Service")
call service.Connect()

'********************************************************
' Get a folder to create a task definition in. 
Dim rootFolder
Set rootFolder = service.GetFolder("\")

' The taskDefinition variable is the TaskDefinition object.
Dim taskDefinition
' The flags parameter is 0 because it is not supported.
Set taskDefinition = service.NewTask(0) 

'********************************************************
' Define information about the task.

' Set the registration info for the task by 
' creating the RegistrationInfo object.
Dim regInfo
Set regInfo = taskDefinition.RegistrationInfo
regInfo.Description = "Start notepad at a certain time"
regInfo.Author = "Administrator"

' Set the task setting info for the Task Scheduler by
' creating a TaskSettings object.
Dim settings
Set settings = taskDefinition.Settings
settings.Enabled = True
settings.StartWhenAvailable = True
settings.Hidden = False

'********************************************************
' Create a time-based trigger.
Dim triggers
Set triggers = taskDefinition.Triggers

Dim trigger
Set trigger = triggers.Create(TriggerTypeTime)

' Trigger variables that define when the trigger is active.
Dim startTime, endTime

Dim time
time = DateAdd("s", 30, Now)  'start time = 30 seconds from now
startTime = XmlTime(time)

time = DateAdd("n", 5, Now) 'end time = 5 minutes from now
endTime = XmlTime(time)

WScript.Echo "startTime :" & startTime
WScript.Echo "endTime :" & endTime

trigger.StartBoundary = startTime
trigger.EndBoundary = endTime
trigger.ExecutionTimeLimit = "PT5M"    'Five minutes
trigger.Id = "TimeTriggerId"
trigger.Enabled = True

'***********************************************************
' Create the action for the task to execute.

' Add an action to the task to run notepad.exe.
Dim Action
Set Action = taskDefinition.Actions.Create( ActionTypeExec )
Action.Path = "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"

WScript.Echo "Task definition created. About to submit the task..."

'***********************************************************
' Register (create) the task.

call rootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition( _
    "Test TimeTrigger", taskDefinition, 6, , , 3)

WScript.Echo "Task submitted."

'------------------------------------------------------------------
' Used to get the time for the trigger 
' startBoundary and endBoundary.
' Return the time in the correct format: 
' YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS. 
'------------------------------------------------------------------
Function XmlTime(t)
    Dim cSecond, cMinute, CHour, cDay, cMonth, cYear
    Dim tTime, tDate

    cSecond = "0" & Second(t)
    cMinute = "0" & Minute(t)
    cHour = "0" & Hour(t)
    cDay = "0" & Day(t)
    cMonth = "0" & Month(t)
    cYear = Year(t)

    tTime = Right(cHour, 2) & ":" & Right(cMinute, 2) & _
        ":" & Right(cSecond, 2)
    tDate = cYear & "-" & Right(cMonth, 2) & "-" & Right(cDay, 2)
    XmlTime = tDate & "T" & tTime 
End Function
```

Comment: The "What if this were possible" thought experiment should help you understand why this is not possible. (All malware would do it!)

Answer (score 2):

You need admin privileges to configure a task to run with admin privileges. So, basically what you're asking is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Actualy, this was a problem in older versions of windows and was widely used by malwares